# A mean to simulate a no-op in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use data to fill in forms (lua string.format instruction) to build tikz commands such as

```lua
"%s \\draw[->,%s,draw=%s,%s](%.3f,%.3f)%s(%.3f,%.3f)node[midway,anchor=base,%s]{%s};"
```

But sometimes, I don't need all the parameters and I wish to have a no-op instruction to consume the parameters of no use.

Is there such a command ? If no, is there a way to simulate it ?

Comment: pgf keys can have defaults. If you provide us with a full example (starting with `\documentclass` etc.), I am sure you will get a full answer.

Comment: @marmot - I have have extra parameters I must consume (because I don't master the parameters list I get) although I don't need them. A default values mechanism, if I understand your proposal, won't be helpful to this respect.

Comment: My main proposal is that you provide a compilable example on which one could build an answer.

Comment: You can define `no-op/.style={}` and then use all your useless parameter as parameters for `no-op`style like this `[no-op={%s}]`.

Comment: @ Kpym - that exactly what I was looking for - I'll implement right away !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments